# How Do I Save Items In Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm new to using Dictionaries in C# and I have a car rental project right now where I want the user to input information about the car and I want the value input by the user to be stored inside a Dictionary.

```
                        Write("Registration Number: ");
                        vehicle.registrationNumber = ReadLine();

                        Write("Brand: ");
                        vehicle.carBrand = ReadLine();

                        Write("Model: ");
                        vehicle.vehicleModel = ReadLine();

                        Write("Type (Sedan, Compact, Subcompact): ");
                        vehicle.vehicleType = ReadLine();

                        Write("Autopilot (Yes, No): ");
                        vehicle.autoPilot = ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you suppose the key-value pair you store in the dictionary to be ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide what types you are going to use for the keys and values. I’m supposing you want to use String for both of them.
You need to declare your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, String> yourDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
```

In order to add a new element use:

```
yourDict.Add("Your Key", "Your value");
```

So the full example may be:

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
Write("Brand: ");
myDict.Add("brand", ReadLine());
```